# IIS7, Server 2008, Static Content

Tags: static, iis-7

Yes, I know its been posted..but if I ask a question on another post I get in trouble for it.

Server 2008, IIS7, static content is installed, enabled, everything looks like it should allow me to serve static files, but I continue to get what appear to be 500's.  I'd really, really love to get beyond this.  I've even added this to my applications web.config to see if it helps:

```
<staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".apk" mimeType="application/vnd.android.package-archive" />
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".jpg" mimeType="image/jpg"/>
</staticContent>
```

Full plate of nada.....any help out there?

Comment: "Yes, I know its been posted..but if I ask a question on another post I get in trouble for it. " Don't post duplicates.

Comment: but I have no answer...and I cant post a follow up question as an answer...or ..whatever.

Comment: It depends on the situation, but just seeing that made me assume that it was non-constructive. It'd help if you linked to the original question and stated how yours was different.

Comment: I'll have to find it.  I've done everything they suggested,(installe/enable static content, enable/install wcf, etc etc)  I have a client and I need to give them direct url access to the apk file I developed, as well as some jpg.  Here's the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9169430/why-is-my-iis-7-refusing-to-serve-up-css-or-js-when-i-change-enable-32-bit-appl